# SOQL to find All Users with a Custom Permission

Tags: soql, query, user, custom-permission

I was looking for a little help to find all users with a particular `Custom Permission` assigned to them, either via `Profile` or `Permission Set`.

Comment: Apart from Adrian's answer here is a good apex class example to look at :
https://github.com/john-brock/Custom-Permissions/blob/master/classes/CustomPermButtons.cls

Comment: @MukeshVerma It's not entirely straightforward how to change direction when you get so many inner-joins involved. Interesting class though.

Comment: Yes @Adrian Larson I understand the complexity. May be it would be good to vote for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DiLXAA0

Comment: @MukeshVerma I had found that class and was using it as a reference but was struggling to adapt it. Others may find it helpful; That's a good addition.

Comment: @MukeshVerma Both of those links are focused on permissions for a *single* user, which actually is not what is being asked here.

Comment: The IdeaExchange URL for this is now moved to https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddRGUAZ/native-apex-support-for-custom-permissions

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update**

Please note that for the *running user*, you can use the [`FeatureManagement`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm) class:

```
Boolean isEnabled = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('My_Permission_Api_Name');
```

---

Surprisingly, I don't think you can do it more simply than the below.

**Execution**

```
public static List<User> getUsersWithCustomPermission(String name)
{
    Set<Id> permissionSetIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (SetupEntityAccess access : [
        SELECT ParentId 
        FROM SetupEntityAccess 
        WHERE SetupEntityId IN (
            SELECT Id 
            FROM CustomPermission 
            WHERE DeveloperName = :name
        )
    ]) {
        permissionSetIds.add(access.ParentId);
    }
    return permissionSetIds.isEmpty() ? new List<User>() : [
        SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
            WHERE PermissionSetId IN :permissionSetIds
        )
    ];
}
```

**Explanation**

At the end of the day, you need to hit four separate tables to make this work.

- `CustomPermission`
- `SetupEntityAccess`
  <sub><sup>(adds the CustomPermission to a PermissionSet)</sup></sub>
- `PermissionSet`
- `PermissionSetAssignment`

You can reduce your queries consumed to two by using inner-joins.

---

**EDIT**

It was mentioned in the comments that you may want to filter for namespace. To do so, I would modify the above join on `CustomPermission` as below:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM CustomPermission 
WHERE DeveloperName = :name
AND NamespacePrefix = null
```

You could also use overloads at the method level:

```
public static List<User> getUsersWithCustomPermission(String name)
{
    return getUsersWithCustomPermission(name, null);
}
public static List<User> getUsersWithCustomPermission(String name, String namespacePrefix)
{
    // use modified queries
}
```

Comment: I was somewhere in the ball Park but was not quite getting the SOQL Correct. You did an excellent Job of laying out the procedure. Thank you

Comment: @Scott as to your comment in the edit history, the ternary is so you don't consume a second query when you know there will be no results.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Makes sense.

Comment: You should probably filter by namespace in this query, as well.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman on which objects?

Comment: `CustomPermission`