# Access Custom Permission on a related User in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, custom-permission

Let's say I have a Custom Permission `Can_Do_the_Thing`, which I've assigned to Users with a Permission Set.

Within Flow, I know that I can check if *the running user* has the Custom Permission using `{!$Permission.Can_Do_the_Thing}`.

However, is it possible to check if a *related User* (e.g., the record Owner) has the Custom Permission? Something like `{!$Record.Owner.Permission.Can_Do_the_Thing}`, or something like that? It really seems like this functionality should exist (and it would be quite useful), but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387530/featuremanagement-checkpermission-not-returning-expected-result/387645#387645) shows you how it is done (apex), you could implement same in Flow (directly or by using invocable apex)